# how to override this to get structured manner

Tags: java, hashmap, linkedhashset

i am creating student management simple java project using Maps collection where id is my key and the name,marks and mobile no. are values for the map. So how to print it in structured manner.

```
HashMap<Integer, LinkedHashSet<StudentCinstructor>> st = new HashMap<>();
LinkedHashSet<StudentCinstructor> st2 = new LinkedHashSet<>();

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
public void add() {
    System.out.println("enter the name of the student");
    String name = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("enter the marks of the student");
    double marks = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("enter the mobile number of the student");
    long mobile_no = sc.nextLong();
    st2.add(new StudentCinstructor(name, marks, mobile_no));
    System.out.println("enter the unique id of the student");
    int id = sc.nextInt();
    st.put(id, st2);
```

with the custom class when i am trying to print it in main method its giving me an address with hashcode.
"HashmapDemo.MethodsForManagement@3d4eac69"

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Also take a look at the documentation for `Object.toString()` and `System.out.println(Object)` to understand the output you're getting.

Comment: do you have multiple values for single id

Comment: It's unclear why you use *sets* of `StudentCinstructor` as your map's values instead of individual `StudentCinstructor` objects.  As the map is populated via the presented `add()` method, none of the sets serving as values in your map will have anything other than exactly one element.

Answer (score 0):

Two remarks :

1- When you try to print the object `StudentCinstructor`, if there is no dedicated `toString()` method, you will not get a well structured output. Therefore, what you need to do is write a `toString()` method for your class and then you can print to console.
Example :

```
public static String toString() {
     return "Customize here + Put this method inside your class";
}
```

2- I don't see why you are using `LinkedHashSet` to store the `StudentCinstructor` objects and then storing this HashSet inside a map rather than creating the `StudentCinstructor` object and storing it in the Map directly if all students have a unique id.
Such as :

`HashMap<Integer, StudentCinstructor> st = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: thanks .i am a beginner in java. I have directly stored it in map. concern is i am taking inputs from the user and i want to print it in structured manner. so where i need to override the to string .....

Comment: You need to put the `toString()` method inside the `StudentCinstructor` class. If you look at @Prasad's answer above, there is an example implementation of it. You can copy that code and put it in your class. Then, when you print out the objects in the map, they will be printed in a structured manner.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your printed output "HashmapDemo.MethodsForManagement@3d4eac69", it seems you are printing an object of class `HashmapDemo.MethodsForManagement`. If you want to print an object of `StudentCinstructor`, you need to pass that object to the print method like `System.out.println(student);`.

And you need to override the `toString()` method in `StudentCinstructor` class. (i.e. put below code in `StudentCinstructor` class.)

(`name`, `marks` and `mobile_no` in below code are the fields in `StudentCinstructor` class.)

```
  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return "Name=" + name + ", Marks=" + marks + ", Mobile number=" + mobile_no;
  }
```